# How to connect an Azure Active Directory to VSO?

Tags: azure, tfs, active-directory, azure-devops

Given a VSO account and an Azure Active Directory, how can I add the AAD to the TFS > Collection > Administration > Security area?  I don't see an option to add another AAD endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

There is good documentation on how to link AAD and VSO on http://visualstudio.com and i have blogged about my experiences.

http://nakedalm.com/use-corporate-identities-existing-vso-accounts/

Ultimately you need to be the Owner of the VSO account and then go to http://portal.azure.com and configure the interaction from the Configuration tab of the account that you want to link.

Answer (score 0):

Adding AAD groups to VSO is not yet supported. If you're trying to connect your VSO account to AAD, check the "Connect your account to your directory" section here https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/setup/manage-organization-access-for-your-account-vs